# return existing file using Java Jersey

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0

I am currently returning a file from Java jersey using an absolute path to a local folder as shown below

```
@Path("/database")
@Stateful
public class DBResource
{
        @GET
        @Path("/get/7zip")
        @Produces("application/7z")
        public StreamingOutput getDatabase()
        {
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/home/jack.jude/myfile.7z");
            return new FileStreamingOutput(file);
        }
}
```

I wonder how can I return a resource from within the application taking into account that

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("");
```

doesn't return a meaningful path and

```
   String rootPath = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

cannot be used because I'm not inside a servlet but inside a Resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to inject `ServletContext` in your resource:

```
@Path("/database")
@Stateful
public class DBResource {

    @Context
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @GET
    @Path("/get/7zip")
    @Produces("application/7z")
    public StreamingOutput getDatabase() {
        servletContext.getRealPath(...);

        ...
    }
}
```